# VBA connecting to SQL Server Express database issue

Tags: sql-server, vba, sql-server-express, adodb

I installed a copy of SQL Server Express (latest). I am having trouble connecting to it.

Since I am the admin on this computer, it should be not needing user name password, because I created the database, and everything should fall under Windows authentication. My code is below.

I get an error:

> Run-time error '-2147217843 (80040e4d)':
>   Invalid authorization specification

This error happens on attempting to open the connection.

When I launch a subform from main form, this code runs in initialize:

```
Option Explicit
Private objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
Private objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Declare variables'
        Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim strSQL As String

        objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Contact;"
        objMyConn.Open

        strSQL = "Select * from Contact where Lastname like " + Chr(39) + "%" + LastSearch + Chr(39) + " And Firstname like " + Chr(39) + "%" + FirstSearch + Chr(39)
        MsgBox strSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: double quotes in a string are escaped my "doubling" .... your sql string can be written as `strSQL = "Select * from Contact where Lastname like ""%" + LastSearch + """ And Firstname like ""%" + FirstSearch + """"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Integrated Security=SSPI` to your connection string to indicate a trusted connection is desired:

```
objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Contact;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

**EDIT**

SQL Server Express installs a named instance by default so you may need to change the data source to include the instance name:

```
objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Contact;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

Comment: Once I do that, I get a different error:  Sql server does not exist or access denied.     Runtime error -21474767259 (80004005)

Comment: @Luv, I updated my answer to specify .\SQLEXPRESS as a server name.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this instead of `localhost`

```
HP8300-0792\SQLEXPRESS
```

where HP8300-0792 is the name of your computer.